# can a timer that fires continuously lead to memory leaks?

Tags: c#

In my program i write data to files if i am not able to connect to database and I have a separate thread that has timer which checks for connection availability after every 25 seconds and if it can connect it transfers the data from files to the main db and deletes the file.
the problem is i never stop this timer,can this lead to memory leaks?
if i just run my program and monitor the task manager i can see the memory usage increasing continuously if i disable the timer and then run my application then the memory is stable

```
    public BackgroundWorker()
    {
        _backgroundWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadEntryPoint));
        _timer = new SWF.Timer();
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        _timer.Interval = 25 * 1000;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool lanAvailabe = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        if (lanAvailabe)
        {
            if (!GetListOfFiles())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
            return;
    }
```

implementation of GetListofFiles()

```
    private bool GetListOfFiles()
    {
        string sourceDirectory = pathOfXmlFiles;
        if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.xml");
        if (!xmlFiles.Any())
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var item in xmlFiles)
        {
            ReadXmlFile(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in xmlFiles)
        {
            if (_writtenToDb)
            {
                File.Delete(item);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

method that reads xml files

```
    private void ReadXmlFile(string filename)
    {
        string[] patientInfo = new string[15];
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
        {
            String line;
            line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (line.IndexOf("<ID>") > 0)
            {
                patientInfo[0] = GetTagValue(line, "<ID>", "</ID>");
            }
            if (line.IndexOf("<PatientID>") > 0)
            {
                patientInfo[1] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientID>", "</PatientID>");
            }
            if (line.IndexOf("<PatientName>") > 0)
            {
                patientInfo[2] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientName>", "</PatientName>");
            }
            if (line.IndexOf("<Room>") > 0)
            {
                patientInfo[3] = GetTagValue(line, "<Room>", "</Room>");
            }

        }
        WriteToDb(patientInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, of course a never-ending timer *can* lead to a memory leak.  But in order to answer your question, we would need to see the implementation of `GetListOfFiles()`.

Comment: Could you tell about SWF namespace?

Comment: @tia using SWF = System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: what is ReadXmlFile ? and little race condition maybe, what happen if it take more than 25 seconds to save in db? what happen in the delete? what happen with the duplicated "insert"? what happen if all file but last got "_written to db" do you delete all files anyway?

Comment: @Fredou i have not included anything for the race condition(and i don't know,can you suggest something) but i check before inserting if it already exists because this is not the only way that i write to main db,and about written to db flag, yes i need to find some other way thakns for valuable comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i just run my program and monitor the task manager i can see the memory usage increasing continuously

Get a profiler. Task Manager is not a right tool. Can't tell what is going on. It doesn't mean that you have a leak. Maybe just GC doesn't run cause there is enough space etc.